# Robot class- KeyEvent fails to upload document to the windows folder at KeyEvent.VK_V

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I am working a specific scenario to upload a doc using selenium. After repeated failure I thought myself to debug the code. Here is my code and the error.

```
public void uploadFile(String imagePath) {
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(imagePath);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

        Robot robot = null;

        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        robot.delay(250);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

While debugging, I found the below result.

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

```
The below happens where the selected path gets printed in the code right next to Vk.Control
```

```
  C:\SAF\GIT\TestImage\Tests.docx       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

```
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Kindly let me know if there are any work around?

Comment: you're just pasting text, right?  You can just use this:  String vKey = "v";    element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL , vKey);

Answer (score 0):

Keep window maximized ,

```
  before robot.delay(250);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

if needed add a bit delay after keyevents ,as below

```
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.delay(50); // it will slow down keyevent renderence and synchronize.
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```